# RESTful service in Spring configuration with jackson-datatype-jsr310

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am trying to configure a Java 8 & Spring 4.3.1 app to use RESTful services.  I get it to work perfectly with the config below, until I introduce a **ContextResolver**.

The reason for the ContextResolver is because I need to format a `java.time.LocalDateTime` to **JSON**.

I first tried with **annotations** on my model bean by adding the **@JsonFormat**,

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = DATE_FORMAT)    
@DateTimeFormat(pattern=DATE_FORMAT) 
@Column(name = "JOINING_DATE", nullable = false)
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.LocalDateTimeType")
private LocalDateTime joiningDate;
```

and got the following **error**:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.JSR310FormattedSerializerBase.findFormatOverrides(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;

Secondly, I removed the @JsonFormat annotation and tried with a **ContextResolver**,

**ObjectMapperContextResolver.java**

```
package com.jobs.spring.configuration;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {  
    private final ObjectMapper MAPPER;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
        MAPPER.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        MAPPER.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return MAPPER;
    }  
}
```

and got the following **error**:

> [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-4) No
>   mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/jbosswildfly/employee/list]
>   in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'

Please can someone advise, I think my Spring configuration may not be correct.

- In the first case, with the **@JsonFormat annotation**, the request
  hits the RESTful service, but gets a **NoSuchMethodError** suggesting
  my dependencies are not correct.
- The second case, with the **ContextResolver**, the request ** doesn't
  find the DispatcherServelet** (and hence doesn't reach the RESTful
  service). This suggests my Spring config is incorrect.

As I said, if I don't use the @JsonFormat annotation or the ContextResolver, I can call the RESTful service successfully (but I need to format the dates).

Thank you

My config as as follows:

**pom.xml**

```
.
.
.
<jackson.version>2.8.0</jackson.version>
.
.
.
        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">

         <servlet>
            <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
         </servlet>

         <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**rest-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jobs.spring" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />    
</beans>
```

**Rest Controller**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping(EmployeeRESTService.BASE_URI)
public class EmployeeRESTService {

    public static final String BASE_URI = "/employee";

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Employee> findAllEmployees() {
        return employeeService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        Long id = employeeService.save(employee);
        return Long.toString(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: What restful framework do you use? Spring RestController or Jersey? Can you also post the code for the RestController or Resource class?

Comment: Hi Wilson, thank you for the help. I was having problems with jackson-datatype-jsr310 as you can see, so have been trying with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter instead.  If you don't mind, could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335917/xmljavatypeadapter-the-xmladapter-never-gets-invoked.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**

By adding the following class, it works now:

```
package com.jobs.spring.configuration;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.indentOutput(true).dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(builder.createXmlMapper(true).build()));
    }
}
```